# What does class Collapse do?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am new to Zurb foundation grids... Can any one explain to me when to use the class 'collapse' in a row?

Answer (score 18):

The `.collapse` class removes the negative margins on the `.row` element and removes the padding on child `.column` elements.

The `.collapse` class on `.row`s is really handy, especially in the case of a nested grid when you don't necessarily want padding between the columns.